# In the Mahabharata, was Shakuni a good person or an evil person by nature?

Tags: mahabharata, evil, shakuni

All we hear about "Shakuni" is that he's a very bad person. Some also say he is the reason behind the Mahabharata war.

I just want to know the real facts about him. Was he good or evil? If he was evil, was he always evil or circumstances forced him to turn evil?

Comment: Shakuni approved of Gandhari's marriage to Dhritarashtra, and nowhere in the Mahabharata is there an indication that Shakuni had any resentment about this; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3082/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, There is no match of your question and mine?Then why did you marked as duplicate remove it now and there is now answer of my question in your answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, the duplicate doesn't match this question. The closest match for duplicate can be: [Why was Shakuni cursed by the gods to be evil?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7424/1049).