# Nature of vidya of dice possessed by Shakuni

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, shakuni

Shakuni wins over the game of dice against Pandavas.

Shakuni declares that no one can defeat him in the game of dice.

Does any statement of Vyasa Mahabharata or any other scripture declare that  Vidya possessed by Shakuni is of bad-natured or by evil means or obtained in the wrong ways?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7424/647