# How can the rishi Rishyasringa have sons / relatives rakshasa?

Tags: mahabharata, rishi, rakshasa

This is something that led me to ask, since in Mahabharata a rakshasa named Alambusha was the son of Rishyasringa while Baka, Kirmira, Hidimba and Alayudha were his relatives.

So my question is, how can Rishyasringa have a son and relatives who are Rakshasa ?

Comment: Related to : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-story-of-alambusha-demon-son-of-sage-rishyasringa?rq=1

Comment: But that's is an unanswered question

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of that question, I ask how can a rishi have a son and rakshasa relatives

Comment: Well Danavas (demons) also have a Rishi (Kashyap) as their father. Does tht surprise u? @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu