# Why is Shanta (Daughter of King Dasratha) not mentioned in Valmiki's Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, scripture

There was a [quiz on Ramayana](https://www.facebook.com/amarchitrakatha/photos/a.314396308601566.68055.313807031993827/1104894032885119/?type=3&comment_id=1104951962879326&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D) yesterday by Amar Chitra Katha.
One of the participants asked this question:

> Which daughter of King Dasharatha and Kaushalya was adopted by the King of Anga Desh and his wife since he had no child of his own ?

I was surprised as I had never heard of this "fact".

I searched and read about [Shanta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanta), and also [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/527/what-scriptures-describe-shanta-as-dasharathas-daughter?rq=1) describes that that there is none in Valmiki's Ramayana, but in Srimad Bhagavatam.

What I want to ask is :

**Why do we have so many versions of [Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana#Variant_versions)(or any other scripture for that matter) which creates confusion**?

Comment: Can you provide the chapter name in Shrimad-Bhagvat please , !! where this statement in mentioned thanks..!! :)

Comment: @ShreeKrishna It's in [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/551/314) by Keshav Srinivasan, he found the [accurate link to it](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/23/7-10).

Comment: Thanks for your replay , stick with me I will check it out ..

Comment: yup, I read the fact ,even in the other source they are telling this fact is not mention in Original Valmiki's Ramayan..

Comment: but make your question correct its ditto look like the other one, you can write like why shanta is not mention in Valmiki ramayan, I know you already mentioned in your question it's different, but u know question should be asked in different way,It's look duplicate of the other question, I know your dobut is different  it;s my sugesstion, but it's up to you brother :) :)

Comment: Ok, you are right, I'll add that as the second question :)

Comment: I changed the question title other-wise it will close as duplicate , and I don't wish it will close as duplicate because it's very interesting and great question ..hope u don't mind.... :) :)

Comment: I think you should also remove the question in bold because that is answered already. Keeping the title in the body would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not right to state that there is no reference to Shanta, daughter of Maharaja Dasharatha and adopted daughter of Anga Raja Romapada in Valmiki Ramayana. In the Tenth Sarga of Balakanda verses 28 to 31 reads as follows:

> तत्र चनीयमने तु विप्रे तस्मिन्महात्मनि |
>    ववर्ष सहसा देवो जगत्प्रह्लादायंस्तदा || २८ ||
>
> वर्षेणैवागतं विप्रं विषयं स्वं नराधिपः |
>   प्रत्युद्गम्य मुनिं प्रीतः शिरसा च महीं गतः || २९ ||
>
> अर्घ्यं च प्रददौ तस्मै नियतः सुसमाहितः |
>   वब्रे प्रसादं विप्रेन्द्रान्मा विप्रं मन्युराविशेत् || ३० ||
>
> **अन्तःपुरं प्रविश्यास्मै कन्यां दत्त्वा यथाविधि |
>
>   शान्तां शान्तेन मनसा राजा हर्षमवाप सः || ३१ ||**
>
> On the Muni reaching the city gates, Lord Indra sent showers to the kingdom of Romapada, which gladdened everyone's heart. The rains betokened the arrive of the Rishi, so thinking Romapada went to receive the Rishi with all humility and welcomed him by offering the high seat, water for abulations and fruits and water for consumption. He also prayed for a boon that his (Rishyashringa's) father Maharishi Vibhandaka should not be angry with the king. **Romapada then took the Rishi Kumar to the women's quarters offered his daughter Shanta of the calm demanaour in marriage performing the rituals as prescribed**.

In the eleventh sarga Dasharatha's minister Sumanta further recounts what he has heard from the Sanat Kumaras of Dasharatha's friendship with Romapada and the request for Rishi Rishyashringa to come and preside over the sacrifice for begetting heirs.

So there is mention of the story of Rishi Rishyashringa and Shanta in Valmiki Ramayana, but yes there is no mention she is Dasharatha's daughter.  That reference as you rightly said is detailed in Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana.